# Office 365 - Word macro to hide text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro to hide bookmarked text in a Word document.  Now that we have upgraded to Office 356, the macro does not work.  I can change other font attributes using this (make the text bold for example), but not hidden. Is the hidden attribute handled in a different way in Office 365?

```
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmark) = True Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmark).Range.Font.Hidden = True

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your macro will work the same in Office 365 as it does in any other Office version. Check whether you have Word configured to display and/or print hidden text.

Comment: If you're the real macropod (the same from MS office forums), then welcome to Stack Overflow! I am graced by your presence.

Comment: Indeed I am the same individual.

Comment: Thank you!  I found that 'Hidden text' is checked by default in 'Always show these formatting marks'; unchecking it removes the hidden text from the display.